# Build a Grid based on two input vectors

Tags: r, function

I'm trying (by using R) to build a "grid" in a matrix based on two input vectors. So, the idea is to avoid nested loop like this:

```
inputVector1=1:4
inputVector2=1:4
grid=NULL
for(i in inputVector1){
  line=NULL
  for(j in inputVector2){
    cellValue=i+j # Instead of i+j it can be anything like taking a value in a dataframe
    line=cbind(line,cellValue)
  }
  grid=rbind(grid,line)
}
```

Is there a dedicated function in R to do this kind of job faster and simpler ? I know there is apply family functions but I didn't found a proper way to do it (without combining multiple apply family functions). Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please provide a set of example vectors and your expected output.

Comment: `?outer` might be what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you, that exactly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Loops *are* kind of simple and they are not necessarily slow. However, it depends on how to use those loops. In your code (I call your approach `L.GUEGAN()`, for further reference), for instance, you don't exploit the fact that you know the size of your ultimate grid and you keep expanding vectors, matrices. That slows things down. A very simple alternative would be

```
niceFor <- function() {
  grid <- matrix(0, nrow = length(inputVector1), ncol = length(inputVector2))
  for(i in seq_along(inputVector1))
    for(j in seq_along(inputVector2))
      grid[i, j] <- i + j
  grid
}
```

where the essential difference is predefining the grid object and updating its values, rather than creating new objects.

2. Yes, you may say that there is a dedicated function for what:

```
outer(inputVector1, inputVector2, `+`)
```

However, one needs to keep in mind that the function in the third argument needs to be vectorized, which is the case in this situation. That is, vectors are allowed when using addition

```
1:2 + 3:4
# [1] 4 6
`+`(1:2, 3:4)
# [1] 4 6
```

However, some other functions are not vectorized. E.g.,

```
seq(3:4, 6:7)
# Error in seq.default(3:4, 6:7) : 'from' must be of length 1
```

In that case, if you use `outer`, take a look at `?Vectorize`.

3. Certain operations have even "more direct" dedicated functions. E.g., if we had

```
grid[i, j] <- i * j
```

Then you should use

```
inputVector1 %*% t(inputVector2)
```

as it would be faster and cleaner than both loops and `outer`.

4. A comparison of the three approaches mentioned before

```
microbenchmark(L.GUEGAN(), niceFor(), funOuter(), times = 2000)
# Unit: microseconds
#        expr    min      lq      mean  median     uq     max neval cld
#  L.GUEGAN() 24.354 33.8645 38.933968 35.6315 40.878 295.661  2000   c
#   niceFor()  4.011  4.7820  6.576742  5.4050  7.697  29.547  2000 a  
#  funOuter()  4.928  6.1935  8.701545  7.3085 10.619  74.449  2000  b
```

So, the nice for loop seems even to be superior if speed matters. Notice that you could further improve it by exploiting symmetry of your grid: you could compute only half of the matrix manually and then use your results to fill the other triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @hrbrmstr this is what I was looking for:

```
outer( 1:4, 1:4, function(a,b){mapply(FUN = function(x,y){return(x+y)},a,b)} )
```